# How to resize debug console in VS code with a keyboard shortcut (while using python)?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I am trying to resize the pane where the debug console is. The command palette suggested

`command + control + up arrow or down arrow`

That works when the terminal is in the pane but not when the debug console is in the pane. Anyone know how to resize the pane without having to have the terminal window the one being selected? Toggling back to the terminal (with `control + ')` to resize the pane seems so silly to me.

---

Related:

- gitissue: https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/51725
- Reddit: https://www.reddit.com/r/vscode/comments/etguf4/how_to_resize_debug_console_in_vs_code_with_a/

Answer (score 0):

Quick shortcut: Hold **Command** and tap **-/+** key to resize. This worked on my mac